# referencing a sheet base on a cell value and its not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

So i need to reference a sheet based on cell value. the sheet name is **PIER X4-320** and i need to get the value of **E31** of that sheet. The sheet name is registered in the cell **A262**. so i used the indirect function,

```
=INDIRECT(A262 & "! $E$31")
```

but i keep getting **#REF!** error with this code. What am i doing wrong here?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have space in sheet name, you have to wrap the sheet name into single quote `'`. Try-

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A262 & "'!$E$31")
```